# Powerpc assembly instruction bl SYM

Tags: powerpc

What is the meaning of "SYM" in the following powerpc assembly code branch instruction?

```
bl SYM (_subroutine)
```

Answer (score 0):

SYM is a macro defined in asm.h

```
#define SYM(x) CONCAT1 (__USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, x)
```

Comment: And __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__ is generally "", so it essentially does nothing.